# Remove anchor text along with external links

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this php script to remove external links (and not internal links) from my wordpress posts:

```
if ( ! preg_match_all( "/(<a.*>)(.*)(<\/a>)/ismU", $content, $outbound_links, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
    return $content;
}

foreach ( $outbound_links as $key => $value ) {
    preg_match( "/href\s*=\s*[\'|\"]\s*(.*)\s*[\'|\"]/i", $value[1], $href );

    if ( ( substr( $href[1], 0, 7 ) != 'http://' && substr( $href[1], 0, 8 ) != 'https://' ) || substr( $href[1], 0, strlen( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ) ) == get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ) {
        unset( $outbound_links[ $key ] );
    } else {
        $content = str_replace( $outbound_links[ $key ][0], $outbound_links[ $key ][2], $content );
    }
}
```

but this script removes the 'a' tags but not the anchor text (for example it will transform `<a href="http://externalsite.com">external site</a>` into `external site`, whereas I also want to erase the anchor text `external site`. So far I have no success modifying this script to do what I want, can you help me here?

Comment: What should be the result of parsing `<a href="http://externalsite.com">external site</a>`?

Comment: can you provide an example value of get_bloginfo( 'url' )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you alter the line beginning with `$content =` like this:

```
if ( ! preg_match_all( "/(<a.*>)(.*)(<\/a>)/ismU", $content, $outbound_links, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
    return $content;
}

foreach ( $outbound_links as $key => $value ) {
    preg_match( "/href\s*=\s*[\'|\"]\s*(.*)\s*[\'|\"]/i", $value[1], $href );

    if ( ( substr( $href[1], 0, 7 ) != 'http://' && substr( $href[1], 0, 8 ) != 'https://' ) || substr( $href[1], 0, strlen( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ) ) == get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ) {
        unset( $outbound_links[ $key ] );
    } else {
        $content = str_replace( $outbound_links[ $key ][0], '', $content );
    }
}
```

The reason is that in it's current state it replaces the link found with the second match in the regular expression, but you want to remove it completely, by replacing it with nothing, ''.